# Amazon S3 Bucket css and js folders not accessible to HTML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a simple static website in an S3 bucket using some boilerplate HTML5 code. I've set permissions on the bucket to Public access universally (all files and folders)

I can't work out why my css and js folders are not loading the content in the `index.html`. The image referenced in the `<img/>` tag is in the root of the project and renders fine.

I've checked the metadata and it seems to be correct e.g. `text/css` for the css files.

Here's the layout:

[image]

Here's the `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <p>My new Website</p>
    <img src="tile.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600" />

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
      window.ga = function () {
        ga.q.push(arguments);
      };
      ga.q = [];
      ga.l = +new Date();
      ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-Y", "auto");
      ga("set", "anonymizeIp", true);
      ga("set", "transport", "beacon");
      ga("send", "pageview");
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside of css folder:

[image]

Permissions on css are as follows:

[image]

Comment: `my css and js folders are not loading the content in the index.html.` is vague - can we see the contents on the HTML file? we need more specific information about what's wrong. Please describe what you're doing, show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks, I added the html file and will try and be more specific

Comment: Thank you - there's no js folder in your S3 bucket? Can you also please add a screenshot of what is inside your JS folder (if exists) and your css folder?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary there is a js folder, it's just not in the screenshot.  It's not picking up any css changes that I make - I added a screenshot of whats in /css

Comment: Do `websitepath/css/normalize.css` in the browser - does it load in the browser on its own?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes, that works and displays the css contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238932/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-steerpike).

Answer (score 0):

This was a permissions issue on one of the css files.

Comment: What specifically? Your original post says that the bucket was configured for public access.